# Proving that a number is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Prove that the following number is an integer:
$$\left( \dfrac{76}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[\large{3}]{77}-\sqrt[\large{3}]{75}}-\sqrt[\large{3}]{5775}}+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{76}{\sqrt[\large{3}]{77}+\sqrt[\large{3}]{75}}+\sqrt[\large{3}]{5775}}\right)^{\large{3}}$$

How can I prove it?

Comment: **Hint** $\ $  more generally replacing $\, 76\to a,\, 75\to a-1,\, 77\to a+1,\, 5776 = 75\cdot77\to a^2-1\,$ the expression equals $\,8(a+1)\ $

Answer (score 15):

**Hint :**

$\sqrt[3]{75}=a$

$\sqrt[3]{77}=b$

$\sqrt[3]{5775}=ab$

$(a^3+b^3)/2=76$

Next , try to simplify expression .

Comment: do i have to solve it in order to show that it's an integer?

Comment: @BukLau First , You should try to simplify expression and then calculate it .

Answer (score 9):

Following the simplifications suggested by MathBot, we have:
$$\left( \dfrac{76}{\dfrac{1}{b-a}-ab}+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{76}{b+a}+ab}\right)^{\large{3}}$$
Let's just take the part inside the parentheses, and put it over a common denominator.
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{76^2}{b+a} + 76 ab + \dfrac{1}{b-a} - ab}{\left(\dfrac{1}{b-a}-ab\right)\left(\dfrac{76}{b+a}+ab\right)}$$
Expand the denominator:
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{76^2}{b+a} + 75 ab + \dfrac{1}{b-a}}{\dfrac{76}{b^2-a^2}+\dfrac{ab}{b-a}- \dfrac{76ab}{b+a}-a^2b^2}$$
Put the numerator and denominator on a common denominator:
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{76^2b - 76^2 a + 75 a b^3 - 75 a^3 b + b + a}{b^2-a^2}}{\dfrac{76 + ab^2 + a^2 b - 76 ab^2 + 76a^2 b - a^2 b^4 + a^4 b^2}{b^2-a^2}}$$
Simplify:
$$\dfrac{76^2b - 76^2 a + 75 a b^3 - 75 a^3 b + b + a}{76 - 75 ab^2 + 77a^2 b - a^2 b^4 + a^4 b^2}$$
Remember that $a^3 = 75$ and $b^3 = 77$:
$$
\dfrac{(76^2 - 75^2 + 1)b + (75 \cdot 77 - 76^2 + 1) a}{76 - 75 ab^2 + 77a^2 b - 77 a^2 b + 75 a b^2}
\ = \ \dfrac{152b + 0 a}{76}
\ = \ 2b.$$
Remember we need to cube the whole thing, so the answer is
$(2b)^3 = 8 b^3 = 8\cdot 77$, or $616$.

Answer (score 8):

we have $$ \left( 76\, \left(  \left( \sqrt [3]{77}-\sqrt [3]{75} \right) ^{-1}-
\sqrt [3]{5775} \right) ^{-1}+ \left( 76\, \left( \sqrt [3]{77}+\sqrt 
[3]{75} \right) ^{-1}+\sqrt [3]{5775} \right) ^{-1} \right) ^{3}
$$
after expanding we obtain
$$438976\, \left(  \left( \sqrt [3]{77}-\sqrt [3]{75} \right) ^{-1}-
\sqrt [3]{5775} \right) ^{-3}+17328\,{\frac {1}{ \left(  \left( \sqrt 
[3]{77}-\sqrt [3]{75} \right) ^{-1}-\sqrt [3]{5775} \right) ^{2}
 \left( 76\, \left( \sqrt [3]{77}+\sqrt [3]{75} \right) ^{-1}+\sqrt [3
]{5775} \right) }}+228\,{\frac {1}{ \left(  \left( \sqrt [3]{77}-
\sqrt [3]{75} \right) ^{-1}-\sqrt [3]{5775} \right)  \left( 76\,
 \left( \sqrt [3]{77}+\sqrt [3]{75} \right) ^{-1}+\sqrt [3]{5775}
 \right) ^{2}}}+ \left( 76\, \left( \sqrt [3]{77}+\sqrt [3]{75}
 \right) ^{-1}+\sqrt [3]{5775} \right) ^{-3}
$$
computing this we obtain
$$616$$
wow

Comment: You are brave to compute this. :p

Comment: i invite you to prove my result

Comment: If you don't have a calculator it is going to take a long, very, very long time to compute directly this as proposed.

Comment: i have my TI-86 by my side

Comment: these problemes are a good training for my students

Comment: where can i find the origing of this problem?

Comment: Such expression. Much math. Wow. +1 for the effort.

Comment: sometimes the simplest proof is a direct proof

Comment: If you are computing it anyway what is the point of expanding first? And how does this prove its an integer? If you are calculating via computers then you can't be sure there isn't some rounding error in there somewhere that makes something very very close to an integer look like an integer. Wouldn't just rearranging and simplifying be a more suitable proof?

Comment: here isn't any rounding error nowhere is a floating point number

Comment: you can try it by yourself and maybe you will find a better way

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Can you clarify what you mean by compute then? You have an expression containing lots of cube roots of numbers that are irrational. They are not going to be able to be stored precisely in a computer so are you doing the calculation or just having something else do the simplification for you?

Comment: you can compute with the roots like with a varíable and this have i done

Comment: see the way by Mathbot

Comment: Ah, that to me is just simplifying. If you are computing that way then internally you are doing what Kundor has done, ie simplifying things. Personally I don't see this as a proof. Its just asking a computer for the answer. Though of course if you trust the computer to be right its proof enough I guess.

Comment: also simplifying is a proof if all steps are equivalent simplifications

Comment: Note that using a TI-86 to "compute" something like this, and believing that it's an integer if that's what the calculator displays, allows one to easily find counter-examples to Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: For those who are unaware, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner is a walking advertisement of WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 1):

The conjugate expression of $\sqrt[3]{a} \pm\sqrt[3]{b}$  is  $\sqrt[3]{a^2} \mp\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2} $. You can use that to rationalise the denominators. The expression inside the parentheses is $\sqrt[3]{77}$  so that finally you get $77$.